# VC++ project, how to define DLL missing error messages?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, dll

So the idea is when the user haven't installed DirectX End-User Runtime the program to show message like "DirectX Runtime missing! Download it from here", instead of the windows loader error (eg.: "d3dx9_43.dll is missing!"). So I find a very funky solution of the problem as I used a delay loaded DLL's and an DLL check before any function defined in the module is invoked using LoadLibrary. If the dll is missing the program shows a user-defined dialog box and exits, otherwise it calls FreeLibrary with the HMODULE returned by LoadLibrary and continues executing. This is implemented as a function like follows:

```
bool CheckResourcesAvailability() //Mainly check for the existence of delay loaded DLL's
{
    HMODULE hMod; //Resourse handle

    if((hMod = LoadLibraryEx(_T("d3d9.dll"), NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE)) == NULL)
    {
        DialogBox(hProgramInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DX_RE), 0, (DLGPROC)&DxRedistMissingDlg);
        return false;
    }

    FreeLibrary(hMod);

    if((hMod = LoadLibraryEx(_T("D3DX9_43.dll"), NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE)) == NULL)
    {
        DialogBox(hProgramInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DX_RE), 0, (DLGPROC)&DxRedistMissingDlg);
        return false;
    }

    FreeLibrary(hMod);

    return true;
}
```

*As DxRedistMissingDlg and MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DX_RE) creates the user-defined error message dialog.

And In WinMain it's called as follows:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    hProgramInstance = hInstance;

#ifndef _DEBUG
    SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS); //Don't display windows error messages
#endif

    //Check for missing delay - loaded dependencies and inform the user
    if(!CheckResourcesAvailability())
        return -1;
    //Some other code.........

}
```

But I don't think this is the cleanest way to do it. First we aren't sure that d3dx9.lib really inherits from D3DX9_43.dll (I know that because I used IDA PRO) and also the LoadLibrary function is called twice - one time at the CheckResourcesAvailability() function and second when the DLL is delay-loaded. Any ideas for a better implementation?

Comment: Why do you have to "LoadLibrary", you can simply do "CreateFile" with "OPEN_EXISTING" flag.

Comment: Because LoadLibrary searches the module in the same way that the loader [do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx). The CreateFile function only opens a file at the specified path without doing any extra searching.

Comment: Yeah that is correct but I thought may be loading the Dll is not the best option as you are only checking only for its existence. Moreover, you can just use "GetFileAttributes" rather than "CreateFile" and about the loading order:: that is well known from the link you have specified. Anyways, just an advice. You can check the performance too with and without LoadLibrary.

Comment: Thanks but my first questions is still unanswered. How can I be sure that d3dx9.lib really requires D3DX9_43.dll? I mean how could I know that dynamically whatever the DX SDK version is?

Comment: The "official" response is going to be that your package should be self-contained, and include the D3D redistributable required. As an admin, I concur, because it makes automatic deployment a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [delay load hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aeywt27.aspx) to let the delay loader notify you whenever a given DLL or a specific exported function is missing.  Not only does that tell you which DLL/function is missing, but also lets you specify a substitute DLL/function if desired.